# Automating Rundeck password MD5 generation

Tags: rundeck

Quick question. I'm using rundeck 3.1.2-20190927 installed via the yum repo on Centos7/RHEL7.

I'm trying to generate the MD5 password using the command line but it looks like its only through the interactive prompts using the WAR file.

ie:
java -jar rundeck-3.1.2-20190927.war --encryptpwd Jetty

Is there a way I can feed it the username/password so I can grep out the MD5 hash instead of having to do this interactively? The documentation is a bit of a mess and I'm seeing references to jetty-all JAR being able to do this but that file isn't in the bootstrap directory, just the WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) as inline script or "external" script to do that without any interaction

```bash
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    spawn java -jar rundeckpro-cluster-3.1.2-20190927.war --encryptpwd Jetty
    expect -exact "Username (Optional, but necessary for Crypt encoding):"
    send -- "user\r"
    expect -exact "*Value To Encrypt (The text you want to encrypt):"
    send -- "user\r"
    expect eof
```