# Rundeck Interaction Prompt

Tags: rundeck

Create a prompt to receive interaction action in between jobs in a running workflow.

From the documentation. the options prompt is only able to put used during the beginning, before executing the workflow

Example:

`echo "Press 'q' to exit"
count=0
while : ; do
read -n 1 k <&1
if [[ $k = q ]] ; then
printf "\nQuitting from the program\n"
break
else
((count=$count+1))
printf "\nIterate for $count times\n"
echo "Press 'q' to exit"
fi
done`

rundeck workflow doesnt accept external input?

Comment: Hi! Can you improve your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to integrate interactive commands/workflows using Rundeck (remember that Rundeck is focused on automation), you can design your steps using [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) tool. Take a look at [this](https://www.slashroot.in/expect-command-tutorial-linux-example-usage), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58504147/10426011) you have a good example.

Also, in your job, you can create options that can pass to your "expect" script using `@option.myoption@` (to pass actions like "yes" or "no" in your interactive script).