# Rundeck operation from Slack

Tags: rundeck

I'm running Terraform script from Rundeck. When I run **terraform plan**, complete output should go to slack. If everything is fine, I need to approve it in slack. Then it should run **terraform apply**.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a job that executes the terraform plan (step) with [slack notification](https://resources.rundeck.com/plugins/slack-notification-plugin/), and using [this app](https://github.com/craig-rueda/rundeck-slack-app) call another job that executes terraform apply (as the same way of the first job). At the moment of call your terraform scripts, maybe a good idea is to use `-auto-approve` [argument](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/apply.html#auto-approve) to avoid the interactive behavior on Rundeck, another alternative is using [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455064/10426011) to execute your terraform scripts.