# Postges command exection without password

Tags: postgresql, rundeck

I want to use rundeck to allow app user to reset their own password without admin access.
So I would like to execute this type of command:

```
export PASSFILE=/usr/pgsql-13/.pgpass ; /usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql -h hostname -U postgres -c """alter user ${job.username} PASSWORD '${option.Password}';"""
```

But the script fails because postgres ask for password
Any one have a workaround? The postgres DB is not a classic DB but aws aurora DB, so I don't have access to pg_hba file

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use interactive commands on Rundeck you can use [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command, in that way you can "wrap" your command to "answer" any interactive command "question", that was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495654/automating-rundeck-password-md5-generation/58504147#58504147).

Answer (score 0):

The environment valuable is called [`PGPASSFILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.7.1.1).

An alternative and simpler way is to specify the `passfile` connection parameter:

```sh
/usr/pgsql-13/bin/psql 'host=hostname user=postgres passfile=/usr/pgsql-13/.pgpass' -c "alter user ${job.username} PASSWORD '${option.Password}';"
```

You can also use the `password` parameter to specify the password in the connect string.